# Minimal differences between R and PMML xgboost probabilities output

Tags: r, xgboost, pmml

I have built an xgboost model in R and exported it in PMML (with r2pmml).
I have tested the same dataset with R and PMML (with Java), the probabilities output are very close but they all have a small difference between 1e-8 and 1e-10.
These differences are too small to be caused by a issue with the input data.

Is it a classic behaviour of rounding between different language/software or I did a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the probabilities output are very close but they all have a small difference between 1e-8 and 1e-10.

The XGBoost library uses `float32` data type (single-precision floating-point), which has a "natural precision" of around 1e-7 .. 1e-8 in this range (probability values, between 0 and 1).

So, your observed difference is less than the "natural precision", and should not be a cause for further concern.

The (J)PMML representation is carrying out exactly the same computations (summation of booster float values, applying a normalization function to it) as the native XGBoost representation.

Comment: Comparing R-printed `float32` values with Java-printed ones could be misleading, because R happily prints extra/non-significant digits (eg. `1.2323456765533`), whereas Java stops right after the last significant digit (eg. `1.2323457`).

Comment: Thanks you, I was thinking about something like this but couldn't find the explanation.